# Only one CPU load on multi core server

Tags: apache-2.2, cpu-usage

top - 01:50:56 up 15 days, 30 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.89, 1.17, 1.11
Tasks: 170 total,   1 running, 169 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie

```
Cpu0  : 56.6%us,  5.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 36.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.9%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  8.3%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  1.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  9.3%us,  1.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 88.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.2%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.9%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  3.7%us,  0.9%sy,  0.9%ni, 94.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Mem:   8180768k total,  7169736k used,  1011032k free,   756132k buffers
Swap:  2104472k total,       24k used,  2104448k free,  5849080k cached

19033 quinroot  20   0  384m  45m  19m S    5  0.6   0:31.52 httpd
19292 quinroot  20   0  375m  35m  18m R    5  0.4   0:15.10 httpd
19474 quinroot  20   0  368m  26m  16m S    5  0.3   0:04.26 httpd
19344 quinroot  20   0  373m  34m  18m S    5  0.4   0:13.30 httpd
19351 quinroot  20   0  373m  33m  18m S    5  0.4   0:12.82 httpd
19455 quinroot  20   0  369m  28m  17m S    5  0.4   0:06.20 httpd
19476 quinroot  20   0  369m  26m  15m R    5  0.3   0:04.48 httpd
19478 quinroot  20   0  368m  25m  14m S    5  0.3   0:04.40 httpd
19540 quinroot  20   0  367m  24m  15m S    5  0.3   0:01.28 httpd
19542 quinroot  20   0  367m  24m  15m S    5  0.3   0:01.26 httpd
19173 quinroot  20   0  379m  41m  19m S    4  0.5   0:24.40 httpd
19290 quinroot  20   0  375m  34m  18m S    4  0.4   0:15.28 httpd
19349 quinroot  20   0  373m  31m  16m S    4  0.4   0:12.86 httpd
19454 quinroot  20   0  369m  29m  17m S    4  0.4   0:06.14 httpd
19475 quinroot  20   0  368m  26m  15m S    4  0.3   0:04.10 httpd
19544 quinroot  20   0  367m  23m  14m S    4  0.3   0:01.28 httpd
19099 quinroot  20   0  380m  42m  20m S    3  0.5   0:25.90 httpd
19293 quinroot  20   0  374m  34m  17m R    3  0.4   0:15.24 httpd
19537 quinroot  20   0  367m  23m  14m S    3  0.3   0:01.08 httpd
19545 quinroot  20   0  367m  23m  14m S    3  0.3   0:01.16 httpd
19526 root      20   0 16940 1348  948 R    1  0.0   0:00.16 top
    1 root      20   0  1064  392  324 S    0  0.0   0:07.62 init
    2 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd

Why Apache always use only one CPU?

Comment: you might need to at least post your apache conf, application name/type, OS and as much detail about what your running as possible...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the load averages, I suspect the webserver isn't busy enough (i.e. serving enough concurrent requests) to require heavy use of multiple CPUs.

As you have many mostly idle httpd processes, you're likely using [MPM prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html) and have MinSpareServers set around 20. Having a number of idle httpd processes is normal, these are used to help Apache quickly respond, when traffic to your webserver increases.

The listing above of instantaneous CPU usage at some time isn't very indicative of long term usage (e.g. it might be an unlucky sample). However, as to why CPU #0 may be favoured:

- Apache MPM prework worker processes with lower PIDs tend to do more work ([as confirmed by this comment](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cM_OVOKybvs/httpd/httpd-2.2.4.tar.bz2%7CW6G7kfsfmHo/httpd-2.2.4/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c&q=apache%202%20prefork%20mpm&d=6&l=816)). For example, the two processes you list with the highest TIME have the lowest process IDs (19033, 19099).
- Linux favours keeping processes on the same CPU, where possible (for cache performance): See man taskset ("Note that the Linux scheduler also supports natural CPU affinity: the scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practical for performance reasons."). Since picking a random CPU is sub optimal (consider power usage), repeat use of CPU #0 seems sensible.

So I'd say your webserver is mostly being served by a couple of processes, and Linux is favouring running them on the same CPU for performance reasons.

If you'd like more information on Apache processes, enable the [ExtendedStatus](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) directive (uncomment the appropriate section in httpd.conf): This enables a status webpage which shows among other things, a list of processes and what they're currently serving.

hope this helps! :)

Lockie